# WCF method is returning empty message element

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I am calling a typical SOAP WCF method `void HelloWorld();`

Unfortunately, it is responding as follows:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<HelloWorld xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"/>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Is there any way I can remove the `<HelloWorld xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"/>` line from the response (basically having an empty `<s:Body>`)?

Comment: It returns name of the method to which call is made. Why do you want to omit it anyway? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will work if you declare this as a "bare" service:

```
[SoapDocumentService(Use = SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
```

Otherwise implement a [custom message inspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx) (and if it dows not work then a [custom message encoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751486.aspx)) to change the message.